# Change values of a DataFrame after pivot

Tags: pandas

I define a DataFrame df2 out of a part of an original DataFrame df following a pivot, I perform some changes on the values of df2 and I want to get the modifications back to the original DataFrame df.
Let df be:

```
In [5]: iterables=[['z3','z2','z1'],['2010','2011','2012','2013']]
   ...: idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['stats', 'dates'])
   ...: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape((12,2)),index=idx, columns=['t','p'])
   ...: df
Out[5]: 
              t   p
stats dates        
z3    2010    0   1
      2011    2   3
      2012    4   5
      2013    6   7
z2    2010    8   9
      2011   10  11
      2012   12  13
      2013   14  15
z1    2010   16  17
      2011   18  19
      2012   20  21
      2013   22  23
```

and df2:

```
df2=df.loc[['z2','z1']].reset_index().pivot(index='dates',columns='stats',values='p')
df2+=1
In [8]: df2
Out[8]: 
stats  z1  z2
dates        
2010   18  10
2011   20  12
2012   22  14
2013   24  16
```

I want to obtain:

```
Out[5]: 
              t   p
stats dates        
z3    2010    0   1
      2011    2   3
      2012    4   5
      2013    6   7
z2    2010    8  10
      2011   10  12
      2012   12  14
      2013   14  16
z1    2010   16  18
      2011   18  20
      2012   20  22
      2013   22  24
```

My naive guess would be to try:

```
df.loc[['z2','z1']].reset_index().pivot(index='dates',columns='stats',values='p')=df2.values
```

which is not suited (SyntaxError: can't assign to function call). How could I do that? 
Many thanks

Comment: Does doing `df.join(df2)` solve your problem?

Comment: No, it adds two new columns with 'z1' and 'z2'.

Comment: Can you post what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: sure here it is, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there, so after you pivot the table, you need to "unpivot" the data, so that it looks like the original dataframe and then join them together. At this point you'll have an additional column and then you want to "coalesce" the two columns together.

In Summary the plan of attack:

1. Make `df2` look like `df`
2. Coalesce the two columns via `combine_first`

**Step 1**

Make `df2` look like `df`. This is done in one line within Python:

```py
# to_frame is just to make it output a pandas dataframe
df2 = df2.unstack().to_frame('p')
```

**Step 2**

To combine them together we need to set the order correctly and just use `combine_first`

```py
df2.combine_first(df)
```

Output

```
                p     t
stats dates            
z1    2010   18.0  16.0
      2011   20.0  18.0
      2012   22.0  20.0
      2013   24.0  22.0
z2    2010   10.0   8.0
      2011   12.0  10.0
      2012   14.0  12.0
      2013   16.0  14.0
z3    2010    1.0   0.0
      2011    3.0   2.0
      2012    5.0   4.0
      2013    7.0   6.0
```

**Full Code and Output**

This is just for completeness to match the question's desired output

```
import pandas as pd
iterables=[['z3','z2','z1'],['2010','2011','2012','2013']]
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['stats', 'dates'])
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape((12,2)),index=idx, columns=['t','p'])

df2=df.loc[['z2','z1']].reset_index().pivot(index='dates',columns='stats',values='p')
df2+=1

df2 = df2.unstack().to_frame('p')
df2.combine_first(df).sort_values('t')[['t', 'p']].astype(int)
```

```
              t   p
stats dates        
z3    2010    0   1
      2011    2   3
      2012    4   5
      2013    6   7
z2    2010    8  10
      2011   10  12
      2012   12  14
      2013   14  16
z1    2010   16  18
      2011   18  20
      2012   20  22
      2013   22  24
```

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer with combine_first. To retrieve the initial format of df and instead of sorting on the 't' column, could we sort/reindex on the  'stats' level according to df original index?

Comment: Yes I think you could resort by the index instead of by values as well (according to the order of the original df)